# Cannot deploy Spring mvc to tomcat in intellij

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to deploy my simple spring MVC project without spring boot to tomcat in IntelliJ, but I can't get it to work, the server always returns 404. I have tried a lot of tutorials but it still doesn't work.

I have also tried AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class but it didn't work either. It seems that the `onStartup` method is never called.

Can someone point out where am I wrong and make it work?

Here is my pom.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web-no-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>5.1.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- core spring dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- provide servlet, web server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- json jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Application.java file

```java
import configuration.RootConfig;
import configuration.WebConfig;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class Application implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.register(WebConfig.class);
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(webContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("app", servlet);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

RootConfig.java file

```java
package configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "controller")
public class RootConfig {
}
```

WebConfig.java file

```java
package configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
}
```

HomeController.java file

```java
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "Hello world from spring";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see any error or exception in your startup log?

Comment: There are no error or exception in the startup log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should add `<packaging>war</packaging>` to your `pom.xml`, but that's not causing the error.

pom.xml

```xml
<groupId>com.learning</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web-no-boot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

You are using two different contexts. If you use only the root context it should work.

Try the following Application.java:

```java
public class Application implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("configuration");
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worked. Thanks. I tried 1 context before but the difference is I used `rootContext.register(RootConfig.class);` instead of `context.setConfigLocation("configuration");`

Answer (score 0):

I think below line might be problem

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "controller")
```

Can you try to change it to

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller"})
```